# Rule association mining - running into unhashable list error

Tags: python

I'm trying to do rule association mining from scratch for an online free course.  The input is a file that contains multiple lines of text.  Each line represents a receipt, and within a receipt are items separated by commas.

My process had been to separate out each line, then separate the items within each line.  However, I think I'm creating lists of lists and then cannot run combinations.  Here is my code so far:

```
item_counts = defaultdict(int)
from itertools import combinations

basket_rules = {}
lines = groceries_file.split("\n")

items = []
for a in lines:
    items.append(a.split(","))

itemset = set(c for c in items)

pair_counts = defaultdict(int)
item_counts = defaultdict(int)

for a, b in combinations(itemset, 2):
    pair_counts[(a,b)] += 1
    pair_counts[(b,a)] += 1
```

The error I get at that last for loop is
    TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

I'm sure there is something obvious I'm missing here.  Please let me know what you think.

Comment: Change `items.append(a.split(","))` to `items.extend(a.split(","))` The error arises in `set(c for c in items)` because `c` is a list (from the line above) and cannot be put into a set since lists are mutable and therefore not hashable.

Comment: Note that `set(c for c in items)` is very much like `set(items)`

Comment: Also, you can use `permutations` and `collections.Counter` together: Something like `pair_counts = Counter(permutations(items, 2))`

Comment: I tried changing it to items.extend instead of items.append and the code did run past the point of error, but now when I print the result, all of the items from all of the receipts are in one long list instead of them being grouped by receipt.